# Does IE have a simple, javascript-driven means of extension development like Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera do?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, userscripts, browser-extension

Before giving up on my extensive googling, I thought I'd make a last ditch effort and ask here...

In Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera - it's very easy to write browser extensions using javascript (and some native javascript functions to each browser)...

I can't seem to find such an equivalent for IE.  I've seen Greasemonkey replacements - most of which only work for very simple scripts.

Does IE9 or 10 support extension development using javascript, rather than C, etc?

I have a pretty large extension working in FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera that I'd be happy to support IE with if it didn't mean a complete rewrite into a different language, but I can't seem to find any sort of IE equivalent of a "content script" or "user javascript" type extension...

Comment: [I don't think so.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ui_and_helpers)

Comment: Try hitting F12. Same kind of idea as chrome console/firebug

Comment: Wow - FF>> +7 years and I start my extensive googling. First promising result landed me right here. I think I'm starting to regret the path I'm on... perhaps I should try bing  :-/

Answer (score 4):

#### Update:

The old *Crossrider* project died a few years ago and the site/domain has moved on to (¿worser?) things.  But then again IE itself has moved on.

But **now [Tampermonkey supports the *Microsoft Edge* browser](https://tampermonkey.net/?ext=dhdg&browser=edge)**.

---

---

**Old obsolete answer:**

It's not quite the ease of Greasemonkey or userscripts, but it's also more powerful.  <del>You can use [**Crossrider**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130102062516/http://crossrider.com/)</del> (archived link) <del>to develop full-on browser extensions that work for IE, as well as Chrome and Firefox.</del>

Crossrider <del>is</del> was coded with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: your link goes to another site

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the only option for IE is to write a [Browser Helper Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object), which is a COM component normally developed in C++ but it is also possible to use .NET. In other words, it would be a complete re-write.

Comment: Isn't Browser Helper Object legacy API? It even listed under "legacy" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I guess the BHO API is considered legacy because it is not supported by Windows 8 metro IE, though there is no Microsoft sanctioned alternative.

Answer (score 0):

BHOs are a mess.

You can do some things with IE Accelerators.  They are relatively easy, but not as powerful as Chrome Extensions.  They are XML driven, and you can install them from your own website, or use Microsoft's gallery.

Here is a blog on creating one.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sudeepg/archive/2009/02/22/creating-a-custom-accelerator-for-internet-explorer-8.aspx

It would be great, if the next MS browser would use some of the techniques Chrome and Firefox have for extensions and apps.  My fingers are crossed.